# asp.net can't take the text of input text

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my aspx

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" >
        <asp:Button id="BookingForDate" runat="server" OnClick="BookingForDate_Click" Text="Search"/> </p> 
    <table id="DateBookingTable" runat="server" style="visibility:hidden">
        <tr><th>ID</th><th>PlanTime</th></tr>
    </table>
```

on my code in c# I can't see `datepicker`

why?

#### note please that i can take all the controllers from id except this one.

I already tried restart the visual studio

Comment: try to add `runat="server"` to your `input`-tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add the `runat`-attribute to your `input`-tag. Try this:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" runat="server">
```

With that change, you should be able to access the element from code behind

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478973.aspx)

Comment: just take a look at the comments of the question :-)

Comment: Absolutely no problem ;)

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 options

add `runat="server"` to the input

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" runat="server" />
```

or create an TextBox

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="datepicker"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should add

```
runat="server"
```

to your input. No you are using an html control and not an asp.net server side control. Hence you can't access the value of the textbox the way you want.

So try the following and then you will be able to access the value of your textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox id="datepicker" runat="server"/>
```

Then in your code behind class you can access the value of this textbox

```
datepicker.Text
```

Another approach, as I pointed initially, it would be the following:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" runat="server">
```

Answer (score 3):

You have not given name to your control and also add runat="server"

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" runat="server" name='datepicker' />
```